# Downloading sound files using urls in R

Tags: r, download

I am trying to download some sound files through R (mostly mp3). I've started off using `download.file()` like below. However, the sound files downloaded this way sound horrible and it's like as if they're playing way too fast. Any ideas?

```
download.file("http://www.mfiles.co.uk/mp3-downloads/frederic-chopin-piano-sonata-2-op35-3-funeral-march.mp3","test.mp3")
```

Even better than if the above function would work, is there a way do download files without having to specify the extension? Sometimes I only have the redirecting page.

Thanks!

Comment: Very unlikely that the file is being corrupted during the download. You are just getting the file as it is. If it doesn't suond good, it's either up to the file or to the way you are reproducing it.

Comment: I might be stupid (it's happened before), but if I download it both using download.file() and manually through IE or whatever and play them using the same media player they do not sound the same.

Comment: Did you check the duration in both cases? I downloaded it and the file lasts 7 minutes and 30 seconds. Is that correct? I can't tell if it's too fast, but it seems normal to me.

Comment: I did in my media players and they show the same duration and the seconds tick by as they should, though using download.file() it ends very early and it sounds awful. Did you try downloading both ways and compare?

Comment: They look the same to me.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but you say they look the same. They do here too. Have you listened to them?

Comment: Lol, of course I listened to them and can't notice any difference.

Comment: Ok thanks. That's so weird since I've tried several media players. Let's hope someone else understands what's wrong!

Comment: Did you try to delete the file and to download it again?

Comment: I did, and I have tried many different mp3s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly setting binary mode with `mode="wb"`:

```
download.file("http://www.mfiles.co.uk/mp3-downloads/frederic-chopin-piano-sonata-2-op35-3-funeral-march.mp3", 
              tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".mp3"), 
              mode="wb")
```

(You can view the filename with `cat(tf)`.)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!